# Validate time in java

Tags: java

I am trying to check if the time the user enters is valid or not, so I am receiving the time as a string in this format hh: mm. However, I want to check if the hours and minutes are valid. I was thinking to convert it from string to int and check it but since it is in this format hh: mm I can't do it. Is there any solution for it?

```
             // New Scanner to get the time from the user
              Scanner timeInput = new Scanner(System.in);

              // Get sunrise + sunset from the user
              System.out.println("Enter time of sunrise [hh: mm]> ");
              String sunrise = timeInput.next();
              System.out.println("Enter time of sunset [hh: mm]>  ");
              String sunset = timeInput.next();
              
              
              try{
                    int number = Integer.parseInt(sunrise);
                    System.out.println(number); 
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: If you want the manual route (vs one of the existing parsers), then you can split the string by `:\s*`, and then parse _those_ strings into integers, checking if they are a valid time.

Comment: Why don't you use regex? (see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: I see no restriction to go for Java's time parser: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
try { LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( input ) ; } 
catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) { … }
```

## Details

[Parse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) as a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html), trap for [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

```
try 
{
    LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( input ) ;
} 
catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) 
{
    …
}
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Dc82gk).

> Valid input produces: 15:30
>
> Oops. Faulty input: 29:30

Your input format of HH:MM in 24-hour clock is defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 standard formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
              Scanner timeInput = new Scanner(System.in);
              System.out.println("Enter time of sunrise [hh: mm]> ");
              String sunrise = timeInput.next();
              System.out.println("Enter time of sunset [hh: mm]>  ");
              String sunset = timeInput.next();
              String sunrise1[]=sunrise.split(":"); // Splitting the string by identifying : inside the string and storing in array
              int hour=Integer.parseInt(sunrise1[0]); //identifying elements based on the array index hours is 0
              int minutes=Integer.parseInt(sunrise1[1]);//minutes is 1
                  if(hour>0 && hour<24){ // performing checks for hour and minutes whether the time is valid or not
                      if(minutes>=0 && minutes<60){
                          System.out.println("Valid time");
                      }else{
                          System.out.println("Minute is not proper");
                      }
                  }else {
                          System.out.println("Time is not proper");
                  }
```